# How to load a BeautifulSoup page parser?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, request

help please download the specified page and find her element with id =''login ". necessarily need to use for the query module request

```
import pprint
import requests

import bs4

url = 'http://forum.saransk.ru/'
html = requests.get(url)
#print(html.text)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
loginForm = soup.find('form', {'id': 'login'})

pprint.pprint(loginForm)
```

error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\VINT\OPENSERVER\OpenServer\domains\localhost\python\parse_html\4_auth\q.py",
>   line 9, in 
>       soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\bs4__init__.py", line 162, in **init**
>       elif len(markup) <= 256: TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to pass the actual html not the request :

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html.text)
```