# "TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()"

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

When I try to execute the code

```
BeautifulSoup(html, ...)
```

it gives the error message

> TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()

I tried passing the actual HTML as a parameter, but it still doesn't work.

```
import requests

url = 'http://vineoftheday.com/?order_by=rating'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to load a page parser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21956956/how-to-load-a-page-parser)

Comment: what version of beautifulsoup are you using?  This seems to work for me

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You are getting `response.content`. But it return response body as bytes ([docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content)). But you should pass `str` to BeautifulSoup constructor ([docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup)). So you need to use the `response.text` instead of getting content.

Answer (score 39):

Try to pass the HTML text directly

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text)
```

Answer (score 11):

`html.parser` is used to ignore the warnings in the page:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")
```

Answer (score 9):

If you're using `requests.get('https://example.com')` to get the HTML, you should use `requests.get('https://example.com').text`.

Answer (score 5):

you are getting only response code in 'response'
and always use browser header for security otherwise 
you will face many issues

Find header in debugger console network section 'header' UserAgent

Try

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from fake_useragent import UserAgent

url = 'http://www.google.com'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(quote_page, headers=headers).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests



url = 'your_url'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use **`.text`** to get content of response

```
import  requests
url = 'http://www ... '
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.text)
```

or use with **soap**

```
import  requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www ... '
response = requests.get(url)
msg = response.text
print(BeautifulSoup(msg,'html.parser'))
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("your_url").text)
```

Now, this code below is better (with lxml parser):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("your_url").text, 'lxml')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = "https://fortnitetracker.com/profile/all/DakshRungta123"
html = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)


title = soup.text
print(title.text)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, provide some explanation about your solution

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

url = 'http://vineoftheday.com/?order_by=rating'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")
```

Comment: Kindly add a line or two to explain what you are doing. This will help the readers to understand the answer more clearly. - [from review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32043912)

Comment: I believe `html,text` is a typo? It should be `html.text` with a period, not a comma. And then, if it's really `html.text`, then that's already the same as this [existing earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36709229/2745495). Please upvote the answer instead.

Comment: @GinoMempin sure bro this is typing mistake