# Python traceback error when using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I know variations of this question have been asked a hundred times, but I haven't been able to find an answer that makes sense for my situation.

I'm new to python and I'm trying to use the following code:

```
import urllib
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

theurl = "https://twitter.com"
thepage = requests.get(theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")

print(soup.title)
```

as a result I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/Users/username/PycharmProjects/WebScraper2.0/web.py", line 8, in
 <module>
     soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py",
 line 192, in __init__
     elif len(markup) <= 256 and ( TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()
```

What is the issue here? I'm still trying to get familiar with the error codes, and this one from what I can tell seems to be pretty general. Anyone feel like helping me out and explaining what the issue is? From the examples i've seen, this should work...what am I missing?

Comment: Is it related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36709165/python-object-of-type-response-has-no-len

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `BeautifulSoup()` around the text of the URL that you grab, not the actual request:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage.text, "html.parser")
```

Comment: That did the trick! thank you! it won't let me accept the answer yet, but as soon as it does I will give you the credit.

Comment: `thepage.content` should also work, not sure of the detailed difference in each though.

Answer (score 0):

Try below snippet :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r=requests.get("https://twitter.com")
c=r.content

soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")

print(soup.title)
```

Comment: The above snippet is a working demo and it gives the result as expected.I can't find the reason for down voting the solution.