# Python, parsing the result from requests to xml

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse the result from requests, to xml by using BeautifulSoup.

However, it returns the error message: "TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()"

Here is my code :

```
r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies, timeout=10)
result = BeautifulSoup(r,'html.parser')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BeautifulSoup: object of type 'Response' has no len()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36709165/beautifulsoup-object-of-type-response-has-no-len)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the content of the response to BeautifulSoup.

**Ex:**

```
result = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 0):

According to a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36709275/6761214) to a similar question:

> You are getting `response.content`. But it return response body as bytes ([docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content)). But you should pass `str` to BeautifulSoup constructor ([docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup)). So you need to use the `response.text` instead of getting content.

Answer (score 0):

Replace r to r.text in BeautifulSoup function:

```
r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies, timeout=10)

result = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
```

Hope it helps. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

In BeautifulSoup, `html.parser` is used for parsing HTML content, if you want to parse XML content, using lxml’s XML parser, like this:

```
result = BeautifulSoup(r,'lxml-xml')   # method 1
result = BeautifulSoup(r,'xml')        # method 2
```

Before you use them, you need ensure you have installed the lxml parser. using pip to install it is easily.

> pip install lxml