# bs4 object of type 'Response' has no len()

Tags: python

I've been trying to get this to work, but keep getting the same TypeError object has no len(). The BeautifulSoup documentation hasn't been any help. This seems to work on every tutorial I watch, and read, but not for me. What am I doing wrong?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

http = requests.get("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0366627/?ref_=nv_sr_1")

print(http)
```

This returns Response [200], but if I try to add soup... I get the len error:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

http = requests.get("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0366627/?ref_=nv_sr_1")    
soup = BeautifulSoup(http, 'lxml')

print(soup)
```

Comment: Direct duplicate of [Python: object of type 'Response' has no len()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36709165/python-object-of-type-response-has-no-len), which in turn is a duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21956956/how-to-load-a-beautifulsoup-page-parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21956956/how-to-load-a-beautifulsoup-page-parser), although this last question and title are not great.

Comment: Please check there is not an existing duplicate SO question, before you ask the same question again. Use the search box in the top right.

Answer (score 1):

As [the docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup) say:

> To parse a document, pass it into the `BeautifulSoup` constructor. You can pass in a string or an open filehandle:

A `Response` object is neither a string nor an open filehandle.

The simplest way to get one of the two, as shown in the first example in [the `requests` docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), is the `.text` attribute. So:

```
http = requests.get("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6738136/?ref_=inth_ov_tt")    
soup = BeautifulSoup(http.text, 'lxml')
```

For other options see [Response Content](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content)—e.g., you can get the bytes with `.content` to let BeautifulSoup guess at the encoding instead of reading it from the headers, or get the socket (which is an open filehandle) with `.raw`.

Answer (score 1):

My final code. It just prints out the title, year and summary, which was all I wanted. Thank all of you for your help.

```
import requests
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

http = requests.get("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0366627/?ref_=nv_sr_1")    
soup = BeautifulSoup(http.content, 'lxml')

title = soup.find("div", class_="title_wrapper").find()
summary = soup.find(class_="summary_text")

print(title.text)
print(summary.text)
```

Answer (score -1):

The Response-200 that you getting from the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
http = requests.get("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6738136/?ref_=inth_ov_tt")    
print(http)
```

shows that the your request is succeeded and returned a response. In-order to parse the HTML code there are two ways:

1. Direct print the text/String format

   import requests
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   http = requests.get("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6738136/?ref_=inth_ov_tt")
   print(http.text)
2. Use a `HTML` parser

   import requests
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   http = requests.get("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6738136/?ref_=inth_ov_tt")
   soup = BeautifulSoup(http.text, 'lxml')
   print(soup)

it is better to use `BeautifulSoup` as using this will allow you to extract the required data from `HTML`, in-case you need it

Comment: Thanks all. I've got more reading to do. Is lxml the preferred parser with soup?

Comment: `lxml` is a 3rd-party HTML parser whereas `html.parser` is a Python built-in HTML parser. Checkout advantages and disadvantages of using different HTML parser(s) [https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser]

Comment: @Keith The docs say "If you can, I recommend you install and use lxml for speed." The only good reasons to use something else are (a) you can't install binary extension modules for some reason, (b) you have badly broken HTML and need to cross your fingers and hope something closer to Mozilla's "quirks mode" might get it right.

Comment: Thanks. lxml was included with my Anaconda Python install. So i'm good. Anaconda Python 3.6.5. But I create conda environments so...